# cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

Getting this error on the `this.realm =` line below. Not sure why as this code worked when it was formatted as a factory function

```
import Realm from 'realm';

export default function Db() {
    this.realm = new Realm({
        schema: [Wallet, WalletAddress, WalletTransaction, Log, APIWallet, APITransaction, APIAccount, Configuration],
        path: config.db_path
    });
    logger(2, realm.path);
}

Db.prototype.doOneToMany = function(one, many) {..};

Db.prototype.query = function(model, filter) {..};

Db.prototype.insert = function(model, options) {..};

Db.prototype.del = function(model, obj) {..};

Db.prototype.update = function(obj, options) {..};

Db.prototype.write = function(func) {..};

Db.prototype.close = function() {..};
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try by removing "default" keyword it will work fine...

```
export function Db() {
this.realm = new Realm({
    schema: [Wallet, WalletAddress, WalletTransaction, Log, APIWallet, APITransaction, APIAccount, Configuration],
    path: config.db_path
});
logger(2, realm.path);}
```

try this...

Comment: That does not work. A new error `_Db2.default is not a constructor` is thrown.