# Can't Access Imported Classes in React Native

Tags: javascript, class, react-native

For some reason we're having a ton of trouble using classes/prototypes in react native... we're not sure if we're doing something wrong, if es6 isn't actually supported or what. How can we use classes in react native? Clearly we aren't doing something right.

**What we've tried**

- Creating a function and adding prototypes to it and exporting at the bottom
- Creating and exporting a class with a constructor
- Importing with {} and without, and exporting with default

**The errors**

- Db is not a constructor
- _Db2.default is not a constructor
- Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
- _Db.Db is not a constructor

No matter what we've tried, we cannot import an object of our creation and instantiate it. [Here is an example of the prototype we've set up in another stackoverflow post we made when trying to untangle the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578503/cannot-read-property-default-of-undefined)

Here is an example of how we're importing it in.

```
import Db from '../localstorage/db/Db';
//var Db = require('../localstorage/db/Db');

const db = new Db();
```

When using require, it seems like the import statement works and an attribute we assign in the constructor exists, but none of the other prototypes are in the object.

**EDIT 1:** Below is our class implementation. We are instantiating realm outside of the class because realm seems to crash when instantiated inside of a class [as documented in this github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1737).

```
const realm = new Realm({
    schema: [Wallet, WalletAddress, WalletTransaction, Log, APIWallet, APITransaction, APIAccount, Configuration],
    path: config.db_path
});

export default class Db extends Object {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.realm = realm;
        logger(2, realm.path);
    }

    //https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#to-many-relationships
    doOneToMany(one, many) {
        many.forEach(m => {
            this.write(() => {
                one.push(m);
            });
        });
    }

    query(model, filter) {
        let results = this.realm.objects(model);
        if (filter) {
            return results.filtered(filter);
        }
        return results;
    }



    insert(model, options) {
        if (options == undefined && model instanceof Realm.Object) {
            this.write(() => {
                realm.create(model);
            });
        } else {
            this.write(() => {
                realm.create(model, options);
            });
        }
    }

    update(obj, options) {
        this.write(() => {
            Object.keys(options).map((key, attribute) => {
                obj[key] = attribute;
            });
        });
    }

    del(model, obj) {
        this.write(() => {
            realm.delete(obj);
        });
    }

    write(func) {
        try {
            realm.write(func);
        } catch (e) {
            logger(0, e);
            throw new Error('Db.js :: Write operation failed ::', e);
        }
    }

    close() {
        Realm.close();
    }
}

//module.exports = { Db };
```

Comment: can you show the DB file? what are you exporting?

Comment: We've rewritten the Db file many times, but the prototype version is in that link. If needed, I can provide our class implementation as well. It worked fine when implemented as a factory function but we needed to manage state better

Comment: Have you tried import {Db} instead of Db ?

Comment: Yes, that results in `_Db.Db is not a constructor`

Comment: Ok then please show me the Class implementation, and Db source file will also help

Comment: Sure, I've made an edit in my original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167953/discussion-between-harsha-goli-and-prollygeek).

Comment: Why are you extending object, and not a component?

Comment: It was just something we were attempting to try, nothing came of it

Comment: Can I fork your repository, and try to investigate the problem further? it is really hard to tell without deep investigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was we had a circular dependency in a Logger.js file that required Db.js while Db.js required Logger for useful logging. Removing the circular dependency caused classes and all the other import issues to go away.